# Linking mongoDB to elasticbeanstalk application

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

So I have this problem where my node application that is ran by Docker in elasticbeanstalk cant establish a connection with mongoDB instance that is in another elasticbeanstalk environment under the same application(it deployed and ran with Docker aswell).
I have made sure that both of them are in the same VPC and that the mongoDB instance accepts inbound connections from the security group that the node application is under(inbound connections are accepted on port 27017).
Node application uses mongoDBs private IP in the connection string. Should work because they are in the same VPC.
Somehow the node application cant connect to the mongoDB instance and it throws the same error always.

```
*** DATABASE ERROR: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [private-ip-here:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND private-ip-here private-ip-here:27017] ***
```

Can anyone give me advice what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: did you comment the bind ip line in mongo config file ?

Comment: No I havent done it. Is this the step I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely reason would  be not configuring mongod.config file in etc directory.

There would  be something like :

```
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment the bindIP or replace it with your server's IP Address.

Comment: added --bindip variable to the Dockerfile sequence(tried with 0.0.0.0 and elasticbeanstalk application private ip). Still it does not establish the connection